# Blank PDFs being uploaded to Google Drive via Google Drive API

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-js-client

I am trying to upload a generated pdf to my google drive folder using [pdfkit](https://pdfkit.org/) and google drive's [api](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads) but every time it's uploaded it's a blank document despite being the same size as the generated labels. I have a separate endpoint which I returns `doc.pipe(res)`  when I call the `createLabel` function and that how I know the pdf was correctly generated, but when I try to sream it my `upload-to-googledrive.js` , the file is successfully uploaded as a **blank** pdf. Does anyone have any suggestions?

**create_label.js**

```js
module.exports.createLabel = async (
    fromAddress,
    toAddress,
    recipient,
    weight,
    qrCodeUrl,
    orderID
) => {
    const doc = new PDFDocument();

    // Rounded Rect is layout
    doc.roundedRect(10, 10, 590, 720, 5).stroke();
    // Fit the image within the dimensions
    doc.image("assets/rocketship.png", 40, 30, { fit: [100, 100] }).stroke();

    doc.rect(20, 20, 200, 150).stroke();
    doc.fontSize(20).font("Times-Bold").text("From:", 230, 30).moveDown(0.5);
    doc.fontSize(18).font("Times-Roman").text(fromAddress);

    doc.rect(220, 20, 370, 150).stroke();
    doc.fontSize(20).font("Times-Bold").text("To:", 30, 180).moveDown(0.5);
    doc.fontSize(18).font("Times-Roman").text(toAddress).moveDown(1);
    doc.fontSize(18).font("Times-Bold").text(recipient).moveDown(1);

    doc.rect(20, 170, 570, 300).stroke();

    doc.rect(20, 470, 270, 250).stroke();
    doc
        .fontSize(20)
        .font("Times-Roman")
        .text(`Order ID: ${orderID}`, 30, 480)
        .moveDown(0.5);
    doc.fontSize(20).font("Times-Roman").text(`Weight: ${weight}`).moveDown(0.5);

    doc.image(qrCodeUrl, 300, 440, { width: 300 });

    doc.rect(290, 470, 300, 250).stroke();

    doc.end();

    return await getStream(doc);
};
```

**index.js**

```js
// other setup code
try {
            const {
                fromAddress,
                recipient,
                shippingPackageId,
                orderID,
                toAddress,
                weight,
            } = req.body;

            logger.info("Attempting to generate QR code");
            const qrCodeUrl = await createQR(shippingPackageId.toString());
            // create label
            logger.info("Attempting to create label");
            const stream = await createLabel(
                fromAddress,
                toAddress,
                recipient,
                weight,
                qrCodeUrl,
                orderID
            );

            logger.info("Uploading to google drive");
            uploadToDrive(orderID, stream);

            //Respond 200 if everything went well
            return res.status(200).send("Succesfully Uploaded to google drive");
        } catch (error) {
            throw res.status(500).send(error);
        }
```

**upload-to-googledrive.js**

```js
module.exports.uploadToDrive = (orderID, stream) => {
// ... google drive setup functions
/**
     * Lists the names and IDs of up to 10 files.
     * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
     */
    function uploadFile(auth) {
        const folderId = `1iAZcU12zgwWC6Iw1eln9kZGx8POhkVLT`;

        const fileMetadata = {
            name: `label_${orderID}.pdf`,
            parents: [folderId],
        };

        const media = {
            mimeType: "application/pdf",
            body: stream,
        };

        const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth });

        drive.files.create(
            {
                resource: fileMetadata,
                media: media,
                fields: "id",
            },
            function (err, file) {
                if (err) {
                    // Handle error
                    throw err;
                } else {
                    console.log("file uploaded");
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

Comment: Can I ask you about `getStream()` in your script?

Comment: Yes sure, it's from the get-stream library https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-stream following a comment here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60346863/5979597 to wait on the completion of the doc before sending over the stream

Comment: Check the stream your not uploading anything.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? When I tested this modification, in my environment, I could confirm that the modified script of `createLabel` worked. But, if that was not the direct solution of your issue, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I saw `doc`, I thought that it is the stream object. So I would like to propose the following modification. Please modify the function of `createLabel` as follows.

#### From:

```
return await getStream(doc);
```

#### To:

```
return doc;
```

#### Reference:

- [PDFKit](https://pdfkit.org/)